# Facebook Like Button not showing in IE even though xmlns in html tag

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, cross-browser, facebook-like, xml-namespaces

My Facebook Like Button works in all browsers except in IE. I've checked stackoverflow and the presented solution was to put some xmlns in the html tag, like this:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
```

I have done that but the like button still doesn't show up.

Other than that, I use the facebook script tag, just under the body tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=99999999";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and the like button:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.example.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="72" data-show-faces="false" data-font="tahoma"></div>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried just creating a new page with only the FB stuff in it and see if that works in IE? Maybe it could be a problem with the container of your FB div? Is this IE9?